# How do I shuffle items in an array, using value as audio source in React?

Tags: reactjs, arrays, algorithm, api

I fetched an array of songs from an API ,mapped over it and  used the string in the array as audio source. Currently I'm trying to add a shuffle functionality to my audio player web app but I don't know where to begin.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to randomize (shuffle) a JavaScript array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2450954/how-to-randomize-shuffle-a-javascript-array)

Comment: Hi, I have checked that post beforehand but it doesn't cover everything. This shuffle will go on to the next item in the array automatically after a song ends.

Comment: Then share your code and explain where you got stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Math.random()` function which returns a floating-point number between `0` and less than `1` then *multiply* it by the *length of* your *array* and pass that number to `Math.floor()` function and use that final number result as the **index** of your *array of songs*.

```js
const songs = ['1st song','2nd song','3rd song', '4th song']

const getRandomSong = max => {
  return songs[Math.floor(Math.random() * max)];
}

const randomSong = document.querySelector('.randomSong');
const btnRandomizer = document.querySelector('.btnRandomizer');
btnRandomizer.addEventListener('click', () => randomSong.textContent = getRandomSong(songs.length))
```

```html
<button class='btnRandomizer'>Randomize</button>
<p>Random song: <span class='randomSong'></span></p>
```

**NOTE:** this example above can seem like its "stuck" at some point, but that's just the way it works for example it can result number `2` twice or 10 or more times *in a row*.

That's why below I've created another example where I'm storing that *randomized* value(`randomNum`) to a global variable (in the outer scope)(`prevNum`).

```js
const songs = ['1st song', '2nd song', '3rd song', '4th song']

let prevNum;
const getRandomSong = max => {
  const randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * max)
  if (prevNum === randomNum) {
    let newRandomNum = randomNum === 0 ? randomNum + 1 : randomNum - 1
    prevNum = newRandomNum;
    return songs[newRandomNum];
  } else {
    prevNum = randomNum;
    return songs[randomNum];
  }
}

const randomSong = document.querySelector('.randomSong');
const btnRandomizer = document.querySelector('.btnRandomizer');
btnRandomizer.addEventListener('click', () => randomSong.textContent = getRandomSong(songs.length))
```

```html
<button class='btnRandomizer'>Randomize</button>
<p>Random song: <span class='randomSong'></span></p>
```

Further explanation *if you are interested* is the part of initializing `newRandomNum` using the ternary operator as to avoid *possible* issue if you were to simply use `+1` or `-1` you may encounter a case scenario where you are trying to access an element above the index of the last element in your array or an index below `0` which in both cases would resolve to `undefined`.